# How to copy entire array in constructor

Tags: android, arrays

i have one class which extends ArrayAdapter
the following is constructor of class. i want to copy the enitire array values to another array of this current class. i am trying like this.values=values;
but it copies only last variable.
how can i copy this entire array?

```
public Custome_res_main_cetegories(Context context, String[] values,String language) {
    super(context, R.layout.custome_main_cetegiores, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.language=language;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use Arrays.copyOf :

```
public Custome_res_main_cetegories(Context context, String[] values,String language) {
    super(context, R.layout.custome_main_cetegiores, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    this.language=language;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public Custome_res_main_cetegories(Context context, String[] values,String language) {
    super(context, R.layout.custome_main_cetegiores, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values.clone();
    this.language=language;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [arraycopy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) work? (found here: http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/06/25/android-quick-tip-use-system-arraycopy/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the `values` Array in your `Array Adapter`.
Just change this line of code in your existing `Code`:
And also rename the Values Array received in the constructor to avoid ambiguity.

```
public Custome_res_main_cetegories(Context context, String[] val ,String language) {
super(context, R.layout.custome_main_cetegiores, values);
this.context = context;
values = new String[val.length];
values = val;
this.language=language;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You should revise this answer as it doesn't copy, just uses the argument as is.